# I want my contract to pay for gas

Tags: gas, contract-invocation

I want to make a contract-to-contract call paying gas not from the user but from the calling contract's balance.

Possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that is not possible.
But your contract could calculate how much gas this call approximately cost and then transfer this amount times the gas price to the user.
However, your contract has no info about the current gas price, so you as the contract owner need to update it manually or use an oracle contract for this.